# Java Stream issue

Tags: java, list, java-8, java-stream

I'm training using streams in java.

That's the request:
returns list of strings
     containing the name of the doctor and the relative number of patients
     sorted by decreasing number.
     The string must be formatted as "### : ID SURNAME NAME" where ###
     represent the number of patients (printed on three characters).

```
public Collection<String> doctorsByNumPatients(){
        SortedMap<Integer, List<String>> a= doctors.values().stream().
                collect(groupingBy(d->d.getPatients().size(), ()->new TreeMap<Integer, List<String>>(reverseOrder()), mapping(Doctor::toString, toList())));

        return a.entrySet().stream().
                ??????????
    }
```

(Doctor::toString returns ID NAME SURNAME)

I wrote this code but i can't finish it cause i don't know how to turn the map into the string's list as suggested in the request, using stream. I solved a similar problem but dealing the map with a loop in which for each iteration I initialized an iterator to scan the value (list) and generate a string for each doctor in any list.

Comment: Why do you store the doctors in a map in the first place? Why not just sort the doctors by patent size in reverse order (using sorted()), and then transform each doctor into a string (using map()), and then collectng the strings into a list (using collect())?

Comment: but how can I save the number of patients for every doctor in that way?

Comment: The number of patients seems to be available using `doctor.getPatients().size()`. Why do you think you need to store that information anywhere else?

Comment: ok i solved like you said. I don't know why I grouped by size. I'm stupid :D However is there a way to solve it after an entrySet is opened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice try.

I suggest:

```
public Collection<String> doctorsByNumPatients() {
    return doctors.values()
            .stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing((Doctor d) -> d.getPatients().size()).reversed())
            .map(d -> String.format("%3d %s", d.getPatients().size(), d.toString()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

As suggested in the comments I am avoiding the intermediate map, just sorting the doctors by number of patients.

Obviously it can be done the way you tried in the question, and it’s not downright stupid. The part you are missing could go like

```
    return a.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .flatMap(e -> e.getValue().stream().map((String s) -> String.format("%3d %s", e.getKey(), s)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

`flatMap()` is the operation to use when each element in your stream contains a collection and you want to process each element of the inner collection as an element in the outer stream. In the `map()` operation in the inner stream we have access to both the inner element, `s`, and the outer element, `e`.

Comment: Thank you!!! I was wrong to answer in this case how to do it cause there's a simple way to solve it. But i found cases in which is the only way to solve it so thank you so much!!

Comment: Prego! Glad you could use it. Feel free to mark as accepted (click on the tick mark to the left of the answer).